# I cannot login to the sharepoint chatroom

Tags: support, chat

I still really don't get it - whenever I want to go to the SharePoint Chat, I keep getting this message:

> Your login data seems too old; please log in to any StackExchange site, possibly logging out before.

Then I will click on the https://chat.stackexchange.com/help (GlobalAuth test) and it will always give me perfect result - meaning no errors as all are ok.

> If logging in still fails, please visit the GlobalAuth test & help page to check for common problems.

I changed my internet browser to Chrome (which was suggested by Vedran) but seems I still could not get to the chatroom.

May I ask if I am missing some details / steps here?

Comment: Did you do what it said?  Log out and log back in?

Comment: I have log out and log in more than 10 times and have restarted my computer too but still cannot log in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am at a loss to explain the error - that message relates (IIRC) to how the global-auth SE login works, but I am investigating.

There is, however, a fallback login method (which is usually advertised if the automated checks find something to complain about) - just navigate to {your Q&A site}/users/chat-stackexchange-login - for example https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/chat-stackexchange-login

Comment: Very Strange! by going though the link you provided - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/chat-stackexchange-login - I am able to access the SharePoint Chat and some more I am using the regular-use internet browser (which before I have problem log in to chat and thus switch to Chrome) and now it works. Marc - You are totally awesome +1! Did you did something at the back-end to help me gain access? or is there a different between the current way of login and the link you provided?

Comment: @Larry no, I didn't change anything. That is our "ghetto fallback for when everything else fails" route (a POST between the two systems). We normally display that if we **detect** a problem, but I'm thinking we should display a "if you *still* can't login" advice, for things we can't detect.

Comment: definitely, I supported the idea - "display the link (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/chat-stackexchange-login) if you still can't login" advice. That will be really very helpful especially for people like me and will help me to save so many hours trying to log-in to the chat.

Comment: @Larry I've just checked - we **do** show that information - see "There is also a secondary option" at the bottom of the test page.

Comment: Thanks and Great, by the way, may I suggest that probably to display a link after that line. (The link can point to the "root" of all the chat rooms and that will be very nice.