# Your login data seems too old; please log in to any Stack Exchange site, possibly logging out before. when trying to login to chat

Tags: support, chat, login, cookies

I use claimid, and I have not been able to login to chat in the past couple of days due to this message.

I tried

- Logging out and in again
- Logging out from SE, then from claim id, then login again
- Using different browsers (Chrome and Firefox)
- Using chrome's incognito mode (which is supposed to have no cookie)

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you not log into _any_ chat site, or is it just SO/just MSO/everything-but-SO-and-MSO? I had this issue in the past for everything-but-SO-and-MSO. Never did get it fixed; it just spontaneously resolved itself one day.

Comment: @PopularDemand I can login to SO, MSO, linguistics.stackexchange.com, etc and have not experienced any login problems in any SEs except chat

Comment: Okay, found the old support chats, but they're not that helpful. Still: first one starts [here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/256430#256430) and there's a room full of them [here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/296/login-problems-on-chat-se).

Comment: Ah, you misunderstood my question. Can you log into chat.SO? What about chat.MSO? Or chat.Linguistics? They run on separate systems.

Comment: wait, turns out that I can log in to http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/ and http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ I cannot login to http://chat.stackexchange.com/ which hosts the [chat for linguistics](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1336/linguistics)

Comment: Hm, so you are facing the same issue I had a year ago. Weird. I'll try to ping balpha (the chat developer) for you, but I can't think of anything else to do.

Comment: Hi Louis - we are trying to check into this; however, please see the workaround as discussed on this similar question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107022/i-cannot-login-to-the-sharepoint-chatroom - in your case I guess you want: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/chat-stackexchange-login

Comment: @MarcGravell Oh wow, that works! Is this ever going to be fixed? The workaround is extremely difficult to find and this error is extremely frustrating.

Comment: @sirtaptap it remains on our list, an we were indeed discussing strategy to remove this earlier this week

Comment: @MarcGravell Great to know, hope it goes smoothly!

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it with a site you've been to today, but go to a site you haven't visited in a while like [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) or [Photo](http://photo.stackexchange.com) does it automatically log you in and show you the message at the top to refresh?

If it doesn't do it automatically, what happens if you then go to the login page?  Will it automatically log you in there without having to click on your login provider?

If it doesn't, log in manually.

Ok, now...log out.  Now go to the login page and login manually.

Now, try chat!

Success?  Maybe?  Can you report back and let me know what happened with each step?

Comment: I tried what @MarcGravell suggested in the comment and it worked